# How to merge two objects that are generated by a mapping process?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, mapping

This is what my original array looks like

```
[                                                                                             
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("12934193c51a231b0165425a"),
    userid: '62921df1c14a2eea0efa9399',
    timestamp: 1653817696599,
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("11934193c51a231b0165425a"),
    userid: '62921df1c14a2eea0efa9399',
    timestamp: 1653817696600,
  }
]
```

I use this code to convert the timestamp

```
const newNotifications = notifications.map((element, index) => {
  return {
    element: element,
    new_timestamp: new Date(element.timestamp),
  };
});
```

And this is the result I have

```
[
  {
    "element": {
      "_id": "12934193c51a231b0165425a",
      "userid": "62921df1c14a2eea0efa9399",
      "timestamp": 1653817696599,
    },
    "timestamp": "2022-05-29T09:48:16.599Z",
  },
]
```

I try to make it look like this

```
[                                                                                             
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("12934193c51a231b0165425a"),
    userid: '62921df1c14a2eea0efa9399',
    timestamp: 1653817696599,
    new_timestamp: '2022-05-29T09:48:16.599Z',
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("11934193c51a231b0165425a"),
    userid: '62921df1c14a2eea0efa9399',
    timestamp: 1653817696600,
    new_timestamp: '2022-05-29T09:48:16.599Z',
  },
]
```

I would like the timestamp to be part of each newly created object and remove the `element` property generated by the current mapping.

Comment: `return {...element, new_timestamp: new Date(element.timestamp)}` in the map method

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `new_timestamp` into the existing object nd then return the whole object **:**

```js
const notifications = [                            
  {
    _id: "12934193c51a231b0165425a",
    userid: '62921df1c14a2eea0efa9399',
    timestamp: 1653817696599,
  },
  {
    _id: "11934193c51a231b0165425a",
    userid: '62921df1c14a2eea0efa9399',
    timestamp: 1653817696600,
  }
];

const newNotifications = notifications.map((element) => {
    element['new_timestamp'] = new Date(element.timestamp).toString()
  return element;
});

console.log(newNotifications);
```

Comment: With this approach, one does not only create a new array (intentionally) but does mutate the object references of the original source array as well (accidentally) ... for the latter case `forEach` was the right method. Since the OP's original mapper function already did create a new object and the problem is about how to merge the `element` sub-structure into the new object, _**cmgchess'**_ comment already provided a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: `forEach` will be beneficial if author wants to modify the original array but as per the code in the question author creating a new array.

Comment: There is a difference in between creating a new array with objects that are structurally different to the objects of the source array and creating a new array with references to mutated source array objects. The OP's intention is very clear about a non mutating approach since the original code and the question both precisely address the OP's goal.

Comment: To me it looks like the downvote comes from having missed the goal.  ... _"`forEach` will be beneficial if author wants to modify the original array but as per the code in the question author creating a new array. – Rohìt Jíndal"_ ... the above approach despite using `map` **does mutate the original array**.

Comment: @timmak ... The above comment has/makes a point. Thus the OP has to decide which approach actually covers the OP's requirements best, `return {...element, new_timestamp: new Date(element.timestamp)}` as suggested by _cmgchess_ or _Rohìt_'s solution.